# How to use this encryption un request?

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I need to perform TDE(Transparent Data Encryption) to encrypt the AdventureWorks2019 database using DEK encryption algorithm RSA_4096, DEK protection using an asymmetric key. I tried to do this in SQLServer 2022 Developer edition. And have problem with this:

> CREATE    DATABASE    ENCRYPTION  KEY WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_4096(Message 102,
> level 15, state 1, line 6 Incorrect syntax around "RSA_4096"
> construct.).

How to fix this?
All request:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE  MASTER  KEY ENCRYPTION  BY  PASSWORD    ='qwerty123';
GO
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY MyAssymKey WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_4096;
GO
USE AdventureWorks2019;
GO
CREATE  DATABASE    ENCRYPTION  KEY 
WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_4096
ENCRYPTION BY SERVER ASYMMETRIC KEY MyAssymKey;
GO
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2019
SET ENCRYPTION ON;
GO
```

I tried to find solutions to similar errors on the Internet, but I couldn't find any. I also looked through the documentation and there is not much about this type of encryption.

Comment: You might look at the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-encryption-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 RSA_4096 is not a valid algorithm for a database encryption key.

Comment: Use `AES_256` instead. DEKs only support AES (and 3DES but you shouldn't use that)